# Getting a function to run when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Major League Baseball</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
   document.writeln( "2013 World Series" );
   var today= new Date()
   $(document).ready(function () {
});
function changeLang(lang) {
    document.cookie = 'myCulture=' + lang;
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
}

link1.onclick = function(e) { return myHandler(e); };

</SCRIPT>
<BODY onload=alert(today)>

<a id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1">Red Sox homepage</a>

<body onload="onload();">
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();"/>



</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to add a javascript function when a link is clicked. I would like the link to open in a new window. Would this be considered a function?

Comment: how about this link? 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: have you looked into the [target="_blank"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)? it might be simpler, depending on what exactly you want to do

Comment: That should work. would you consider this a javascript function?

Comment: Seems like your "so far" is a bunch of unrelated code pasted together.

Comment: no, I wouldn't consider `target="_blank"` a javascript function - it's part of the html/DOM. It's an attribute for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: do you have an example of something that would be a javascript function involving a link? It doesn't need to be something complicated.

Comment: I posted an example below - no jquery, pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
        //any misc code
        //window.open('URL','name of url'); <-- to open a new window/tab
    });
```

edit -- missing 's

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
<a id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1">Red Sox homepage</a>
```

to

```
<a id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1" target="_blank">Red Sox homepage</a>
```

And I would use this to execute a function when this link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myHandler(text) {
        alert(text);
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'a#link1', function() {
        myHandler($(this).attr('href'));
    });
</script>
```

Edit: Should work when u use this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Major League Baseball</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myHandler(text) {
            alert(text);
        }

        $(document).on('click', 'a#link1', function() {
            myHandler($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1">Red Sox homepage</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What is the function you used as an example supposed to do? I added it to my document and it doesn't appear to be doing anything special.

Comment: myHandler is an example, non-existing function. You can define a function for whatever you wanna do before the `$(document).on('click', 'a#link1', function() {` line. `function myHandler() {
        alert('hello');
    }` 

would give an alert when you click the link.

Comment: <Script type="text/javascript">
 function myHandler() { alert('hello'); }
    $(document).on('click', 'a#link1', function() {
        myHandler();
    });

</SCRIPT>

Comment: that's what it looks like on my document but when I click the link the alert doesn't pop up. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Added a function to my answer. Copy/paste this and it should alert the href of the link. See http://api.jquery.com/ for more functions with JQuery.

Comment: You forgot to load the JQuery library. Copy/paste this between the </title> and </head> tags: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I copied and pasted what you had and it still isn't popping up with anything. I'm using javascript not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments the following would achieve what you need - I think. (no Jquery, pure javascript)

```
<script>
function someFunction(){
    alert("You called a function on the link click");
}
</script>
<a target="_blank" onclick="someFunction()" id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1">Red Sox homepage</a>
```

Comment: could you be more specific? what would you write instead of writing "someFunction"

Comment: If you notice within the script tag, I have a function called `someFunction()` 

As long as onclick references a function you declared it will work.

Comment: Used your example. Nothing happens when I click on the link.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is change your link to have a target...so just change it to:

```
<a id="link1" href="http://boston.redsox.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=bos&sv=1" target="redsox">
```

No javascript required.